# Twitter phone verification while on Tor

Tags: privacy, tor, phone, twitter

Twitter locked me out of my account.  I can log in but I can't do anything with it until I give them a phone number.

I've had the account for years but they've decided now there's "suspicious activity" with it.  I've tried many of the free online receive SMS services but Twitter has them all blocked.

Is there anything out there I can use without downloading something?  I've found virtual android services that can be downloaded for the PC but that would mean they could see my VPN's IP.  Others want a Gmail which means it requires a phone number.  Which defeats the purpose of doing all this on Tor trying to avoid phone verification forced on you.

I'm looking for a solution that includes any method performed online via Tor that:

- Doesn't require a download
- Doesn't require giving any personal information
- Hasn't been blacklisted by Twitter yet

Comment: so, basically, you're asking about an online SMS tool?

Comment: I think your question will be better if you use *any method* instead of *anything*; this last term sounds like you are recommending a software, that is why someone downvoted you (software recommendations are banned here)

Comment: No software or downloads.  That would mean it would get my VPN IP.  I want anything that can be done only through Tor that doesn't require personal information and hasn't been blacklisted by Twitter yet.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter seems to have [a complicated history](http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/02/twitter-tor-phone-verification/) with Tor's users. The linked article seems to doubt of Twitter explaining they do not put any specific restriction against Tor's IP:

> Twitter does not block or force Tor users to phone verify in order to
>   sign up. Occasionally, signups and logins may be asked to phone verify
>   as they may exhibit behavior similar to spam. This is applicable to
>   all IPs and not just Tor IPs.

However, chances are that such restriction are effectively caused by a side-effect of using Tor. Indeed, when using Tor you share the same IP address pool than all the other users, including malicious ones. Twitter servers have no way to ensure that the request coming from an IP which was once used by a spammer now comes from a legit user.

That's why, while Tor may indeed not be specifically targeted by Twitter's management, de facto as established by the linked article using an address from Tor's network put you directly under the suspicious users category.

As per the SMS check, in some country there are low-cost cellphone available as stopgap solution and requiring no identity verification during the first few weeks of usage. You may buy one, validate Twitter SMS, then dispose of it. However be concious that after such procedure your account will be linked with a phone number you do not own anymore and which will be allocated to an unknown person.

Otherwise, you may want to tackle this IP address at the root. Some VPN provider offer the possibility to get you a static dedicated IP address. Thanks to such service, you will be granted a dedicated IP address used only by you (and not shared with some other spammers), exactly like any common Internet users, but with the major difference that this IP address will be not linked to your actual location and identity. If anonymity truly matters, you will still prefer to use Tor between you and this VPN server (to ensure that no one can trace you back from the VPN provider system) and ensure that no other data can link you to this VPN server (payment system used, use Tor to subscribe a specific email account, etc.).